# Unexplained boost in execution speed for 1 pandas column versus 2

Tags: python, pandas

I'm experiencing an incredible difference in execution speed when using a single column Pandas data frame versus two.

Here are two code samples I'm comparing when using a data frame that initially has two columns of data.

```
m=[' BOULEVARD ',' AVE',' CT',' DR',' LN',' PATH',' PL',' RD',' ST',' TER',' WAY',' BLVD',' PSGE',' CIR',' HWY',' CSWY',' TRL',' PKWY']

#OPTION 1
for r in range(0,data.shape[0]):
        s=str(data.loc[r,"Property Address"])
        num=s.find(' ')
        data.loc[r,"Street Number"]=s[:num]
        s=(s[num:])   
        data.loc[r,"Remaining"]=s

        for ms in m:
            if ms in s:)
                data.loc[r,"Number"]=s[s.find(ms)+len(ms):]
                data.loc[r,"Cleaned_Addr"]=s[:s.find(ms)+len(ms)]

#OPTION2
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    try:
        print (str(index)+""+str(data.shape[0]))
        num=str(data.loc[index,"Property Address"]).find(' ')
        data.loc[index,"Street Number"]=data.loc[index,"Property Address"][:num]
        s=(data.loc[index,"Property Address"][num:])
        for ms in m:
            if ms in s:
                data.loc[index,"Number"]=s[s.find(ms)+len(ms):]
                data.loc[index,"Cleaned_Addr"]=s[:s.find(ms)+len(ms)]
    except:pass
```

The two code samples above have a comparable execution speed when processing a data frame that initially has two columns of data.
I made Option 2 hoping that iterrows() would speed things up but it runs at nearly the same speed.

But once I use a single column data frame with Option 1, it runs super fast.
Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Could be because of the data in that one column as compared to the other columns. Can you provide a snippet of the original dataframe?

Comment: It's just a column of addresses like "9999 SW 156 TER" and maybe an index. I've noticed that in order to have the fast performance, the shape function (df.shape) has to return (#of rows, 1) and performs slowly when you have a shape of (#of rows, 2) or (#of rows, )